# LINQ to Entities - Simple Way to split resultset into multiple objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table, containing weekly sales data from multiple years for a few hundred products.
Simplified, I have 3 columns: ProductID, Quantity, [and Date (week/year), not relevant for the question]

In order to process the data, i want to fetch everything using LINQ. In the next step I would like create a List of Objects for the sales data, where an Object consists of the ProductId and an array of the corresponding sales data.

EDIT: directly after, I will process all the retrieved data product-by-product in my program by passing the sales as an array to a statistics software (R with R dot NET) in order to get predictions.

Is there a simple (built in) way to accomplish this?

If not, in order to process the sales product by product,
should I just create the mentioned List using a loop?

Or should I, in terms of performance, avoid that all together and:

Fetch the sales data product-by-product from the database as I need it?

Or should I make one big List (with query.toList()) from the resultset and get my sales data product-by-product from there?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking (some sample code, example of input and expected output could make this question better), but maybe you need grouping by productID. Can't tell you more from information you provided

Comment: From first glance: Have a look at the [GroupBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy%60%602%22)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2cVersion%3dv4.5)%3bk(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method.

Comment: I need an array of the sales data for every product - see edit.

Comment: @MartinZotter what is sales data? Array of quantity values?

Comment: Yeah, just an array of int values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erm, something like

```
var groupedByProductId = query.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId).Select(g => new
        {
            ProdcutId = g.Key,
            Quantity = g.Sum(p => p.Quantity)
        });
```

or perhaps, if you don't want to sum and, instread need the quantities as an array of `int` ordered by `Date`.

```
var groupedByProductId = query.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId).Select(g => new
        {
            ProdcutId = g.Key,
            Quantities = g.OrderBy(p => p.Date).Select(p => p.Quantity).ToArray()
        });
```

or maybe you need to pass the data around and an anonymous type is inappropriate., you could make an `IDictionary<int, int[]>`.

```
var salesData = query.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId).ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.OrderBy(p => p.Date).Select(p => p.Quantity).ToArray());
```

so later,

```
int productId = ...
int[] orderedQuantities = salesData[productId];
```

would be valid code (less the ellipsis.)

Comment: @MartinZotter, Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: no, its exactly what i was looking for, especially the IDictionary should be a good approach for my needs

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Product class with id and list of int data. Something as below:

```
Public class Product{

public List<int> list = new List<int>();
public int Id;
Public Product(int id,params int[] list){
   Id = id;
   for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            list.Add(list[i]);
        }
}
}
```

Then use:

```
query.where(x=>new Product(x.ProductId,x.datum1,x.datum2,x.datum3));
```